# Customize GAE page when instance is stopped

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

If the GAE instance is stopped, we have the current window shown:

> Error: Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.

[image: Error: Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.]

Can we customize this page with other templates?

Standard instance with python2.7 lang

Comment: No, Google does not provide that as an option.

Comment: An error handler in the `app.yaml` comes to mind, or doing a redirect whithin the code to the page of choice, but since neither is really running or being used (unless perhaps if it is cached), I think it's safe to assume it's not possible.

Comment: app engine standard or flex ? which language ? I don't understand how you can get a response from an instance that is not yet up